How to compute probability intervals for ARIMA model using conformal prediction?
Every time I am trying to read about conformal prediction probability intervals, I find people talking briefly about how to do it and dive deep into how to use a specific package. I want to learn the algorithm behind the construction of the probability intervals.

Try the forecast package from R, and play around with forecasting different time series using the template below.
AirPassengers |> auto.arima(trace = TRUE) |> forecast(h=24) |> autoplot()
You can read more about ARIMA prediction intervals at
https://otexts.com/fpp3/arima-forecasting.html.
